# Encoding Javascript Object to Json string

Tags: javascript, object, json, javascript-objects

I want to encode a Javascript object into a JSON string and I am having considerable difficulties.

The Object looks something like this

```
new_tweets[k]['tweet_id'] = 98745521;
new_tweets[k]['user_id'] = 54875;       
new_tweets[k]['data']['in_reply_to_screen_name'] = "other_user";
new_tweets[k]['data']['text'] = "tweet text";
```

I want to get this into a JSON string to put it into an ajax request.

```
{'k':{'tweet_id':98745521,'user_id':54875, 'data':{...}}}
```

you get the picture. No matter what I do, it just doesn't work. All the JSON encoders like json2 and such produce

```
[]
```

Well, that does not help me. Basically I would like to have something like the php `encodejson` function.

Comment: what did you actually try? please provide some code of your trials...

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Unless the variable `k` is defined, that's probably what's causing your trouble.  Something like this will do what you want:

```
var new_tweets = { };

new_tweets.k = { };

new_tweets.k.tweet_id = 98745521;
new_tweets.k.user_id = 54875;

new_tweets.k.data = { };

new_tweets.k.data.in_reply_to_screen_name = 'other_user';
new_tweets.k.data.text = 'tweet text';

// Will create the JSON string you're looking for.
var json = JSON.stringify(new_tweets);
```

You can also do it all at once:

```
var new_tweets = {
  k: {
    tweet_id: 98745521,
    user_id: 54875,
    data: {
      in_reply_to_screen_name: 'other_user',
      text: 'tweet_text'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you very much. The k was defined. The problem was me being stupid using new Array() instead of an object {}.

Comment: Works perfect... I make a test and result are awesome. Thanks. 

`console.info(json);
console.log(new_tweets["k"]);
console.log(new_tweets["k"]["user_id"]);
console.log(new_tweets["k"]["data"]["text"]);`

Comment: After all this time reading about CORS and Chrome security, this is a simple and effective way to encode JSON data. A very well-deserved +1

Comment: @TomášZato: Why specifically would it be? `JSON.stringify` predates PHP's `json_encode`, if that's what you're alluding to.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking. I found out about `JSON` very recently. In past, I used `eval` to parse JSON responses. I was happy the eval will be gon from my code.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like:

```
JSON.stringify(new_tweets);
```