# How to encode array name based input to pass via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, encode

I need send via AJAX data like the following:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="textbox" value="12" name="delay[256]"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="256" name="attach_to[]"></td>
</tr>                       
<tr>
<td><input type="textbox" value="7" name="delay[653]"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value="653" name="attach_to[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Which is the best way to encode these 2 types of input?

```
$.post(
window.location.href,
{
    data_ajax: 1,
    attach_to : attach_to, // how encode?
    delay: delay // how encode?

},
function(array) {
},
'json'
);
```

OBS: I only want send these data and not the entire form. So `.serialize()` seems not adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

js code: `serialize()` works over an entire form or given elements.

```
var attach_to = $("input[name='attach_to[]']").serialize();
var delay = $("input[name^='delay[']").serialize();
$.post(
    window.location.href,
    {
        attach_to : attach_to,
        delay: delay
    },
    function(array) {
        // ...
    },
    'json'
    );
```

php code: `parse_str` is the key to easily decode incoming vars.

```
parse_str($_REQUEST['delay'], $params);
$delay = $params['delay'];
parse_str($_REQUEST['attach_to'], $params);
$attach_to = $params['attach_to'];
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to learn how to encode the data as JSON: [Encoding Javascript Object to Json string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810084/encoding-javascript-object-to-json-string)

And then read the posted JSON variables back into an array with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I don't think is a good idea send json (JavaScript Object Notation) code to php. The opposite make more sense (`echo json_encode($output); -> js`). But thanks!