# storing javascript array with special characters inside a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i searched around stackoverflow and found out that cookie only can store string not array.

i have an array like this:

```
  var myvar = {
   'comment' : '123',
   'blog' : 'blog',
   'test' : '321
  }
```

Then i use this jquery plugin to manage the cookies: 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

I use the below code to store the cookie named 'setting':

```
  $.cookie('setting',  myvar , { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

However how do i convert that array into a string , i know i can use .join , but what if my array values for example comment , is a special character like Chinese characters etc.

and how can i access the cookie again and get the string out and convert it again into an array?

Comment: That's an object (not an array). I'd suggest taking a look at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810084/encoding-javascript-object-to-json-string , it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store an object in a cookie:

```
var myvar = {
   'comment' : '123',
   'blog' : 'blog',
   'test' : '321'
};

var serialized = JSON.stringify(myvar);

$.cookie('setting', serialized, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
```

To retrieve an object from a cookie :

```
JSON.parse($.cookie("setting"));
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery) for examples of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.