# How to send JSON data in an Ajax request?

Tags: html, ajax, json

what would be the best way to send string (unicode text) & array-of-string data (several hundreds characters, for now formatted as a single Json object) from an HTML page to a PHP server document (to be then recorded in a db)?  I'm pretty much new at Json and I'm not sure how to send a Json object server side with an Ajax call.

Right now, my idea would be to somehow serialize my Json object into a string, then send that string as a parameter to a `POST` Ajax call, but again, I'm not sure if this is the right way or how to serialize Json.

I don't use jquery at this time.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a textual data exchange format. What you can do is convert any data you have (object, array) to JSON, i.e. to a string containing JSON formatted data, and then send it as usual as POST data. Use `JSON.stringify` to convert an array or object to JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your link.  I was actually confused on whether Json was simply a set of rules on how to format strings, or whether it had more dimensions.

Comment: See JSON as XML, CSV or YAML. It's a data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON.stringify as you suggested.

[JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810084/encoding-javascript-object-to-json-string)

But why do you want to serialize as JSON on the client side as opposed to sending as is to the server and converting to JSON on the server side? Then you could use a JSON library in whatever language your server supports.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. The data has to be converted to JSON on the client in order to parse it as JSON on the server. Converting the data *to* JSON on the *server* does not seem to make sense. And sending data "as is" is not always possible if you have arrays or objects.

Comment: I was asking the reason why it has to be converted on the client side to JSON. I guess that may have to do with what your server expects.

Comment: Since I need to get a bunch of data together into a string, I might as well format that string in Json - that or xml, no?

Comment: Yes you could. But you could also send them as separate strings as POST parameters.