# Esri ArcGIS Print the map

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I am using ArcGIS javaScript 3.5 and i want to implement the print map.I know it is a in-built tool we can use that service also but my problem is to implement the all three step(Print,Printing,PrintOut) in one click (Prefer some other click).

for that purpose i did something like---

first i added one div in design level and set visiblity as false

```
   <div id="print_button" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></div>
```

In init i use esri.dijit.Print option

```
        var app = {};
        app.webmapId = "8315cf7d20f0484e869c4791f70f4f15";
        app.printUrl = "abc/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task";

        var layouts = [{
            "name": "Letter ANSI A Landscape",
            "label": "Landscape (PDF)",
            "format": "pdf",
            "options": {
                "legendLayers": [], // empty array means no legend
                "scalebarUnit": "Miles",
                "titleText": "Map"
            }
        }];
        var templates = [];
        dojo.forEach(layouts, function (lo) {
            var t = new esri.tasks.PrintTemplate();
            t.layout = lo.name;
            t.label = lo.label;
            t.format = lo.format;
            t.layoutOptions = lo.options
            templates.push(t);
        });


        app.printer = new esri.dijit.Print({
            "map": map,
            "templates": templates,
            url: app.printUrl,
        }, dojo.byId("print_button"));
        app.printer.startup();
```

and in my click internally i want to click this print button

```
function export1() { 
        document.getElementById('print_button').click();//This is not working obviously this is not a button        
        return false;
    }
```

How can i achive this.   Please help me.

---

After Anyalysis this div i found these elements

```
<div class="esriPrint">
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton esriPrintButton dijitButtonDisabled dijitDisabled" 
    role="presentation" widgetId="dijit_form_Button_0">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick">
        <span disabled="" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" id="dijit_form_Button_0" role="button" aria-disabled="true" 
          aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_0_label" style="-ms-user-select: none;" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode">
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">
            </span>

            <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">
            ●
            </span>

            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_0_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
            Printing
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input tabindex="-1" disabled="" class="dijitOffScreen" role="presentation" type="button" value="" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span></div>


<div class="esriPrint">
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton esriPrintButton" role="presentation" widgetId="dijit_form_Button_1">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick">
        <span tabindex="0" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" id="dijit_form_Button_1" 
        role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_1_label" style="-ms-user-select: none;" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode">

            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode">
            </span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">
            ●
            </span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_1_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
            Print
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
<input tabindex="-1" class="dijitOffScreen" role="presentation" type="button" value="" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span></div>
```

but how can i call this click event because it simple to find the element but it is not simple to call click event or i dont know how to call  data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" this event ?

Can u suggest me how to call this event ?

Comment: technically nice joke @Juffy but this is not the right time to do . if u have any answer then post....

Comment: Granted, it wasn't helpful. And maybe there's a failure in translation, but waiting just 7 hours (remembering that this is a global site, and some of us were asleep) before demanding an answer isn't going to win you any friends. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not a complete answer, I think the reason your `.click()` is failing is because you're 'clicking' the wrong thing. In the source code of my map, all I have is:

```
<div id="printButton"></div>
```

but at runtime Dojo expands that out to:

```
<div id="printButton">
  <div class="esriPrint">
    <span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline esriPrintButton dijitButton" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_0">
      <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" role="presentation">
...etc
```

and note the `data-dojo-attach-event` tag on the second `<span>` tag. I would look at locating that `<span>` tag and seeing if you can raise a click event on it.

---

**EDIT:**

Yep, `.click()`ing the correct element DOES fire the print task, I've just tried it in my own application. I use jQuery extensively, so I used the selector `#printButton .dijitInline` to find any element with the class `.dijitInline` which is a child of the `<div id="printButton">`:

```
$('#printButton .dijitInline').click();
```

...and that fired off the print task exactly as if I'd clicked the button with the mouse. You should be able to use the [dojo equivalent](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html) to find the right element and click it.

Comment: Thanks @Juffy for reply again. And i know that this  document.getElementById('print_button').click() will not work because it is a div.

Comment: No, it's not because it's a div - div's are perfectly click'able. It's because there's no onClick() behaviour defined for that div, the intelligent part is in a child node.

Comment: I used like:  require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom"], function (query, dom) {
                var node = dom.byId("print_button");
                nl = query(".dijitButtonNode", node);
                if (nl.length > 0)
                    nl[0].click();                     
            });

Comment: Is there any other way like direct call print event which that print_button is using... because i am getting so many problem..

Comment: Hello there i am trying to call  PrintingTools (GPServer) - Export Web Map Task - execute  manually .

for that purpose i need to change my map object into json object (Web Map as JSON:(GPString)). this is the first argument. 

so i can construct the json object manually but

is there any method to get Json object directly in Arcgis javascript 3.5 APIs ?

Comment: Umm...there's plenty of [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810084/encoding-javascript-object-to-json-string) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919965/how-do-i-encode-a-javascript-object-as-json) on creating JSON objects. If that's not what you're trying to do then I would suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: can we directly change map object to JSon object ? like Print_button is doing.
And i have one more question do u know where is this Print_Button.Click() event is coded ?

Comment: By 'ask a new question' I mean post a new question using the 'Ask Question' button in the top right, not ask more questions in this thread.