# FormData to JSON w/o jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, form-data

How do I serialize a FormData object into JSON without using jQuery, and then send it with a raw XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: By looping over form's input making a hash of name and values

Comment: possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810084/encoding-javascript-object-to-json-string